# Accidentally began localepurge installation, didn't select locales to keep, not sure what to do

Tags: dpkg, locale

This is my first time on this site so I hope this question is okay. Anyway, I'm relatively new to linux. I did look around for resources and tried to find anything that I could manage myself, however, there's not much information about this specifically.

About 3 hours ago I ran sudo apt-get install localepurge, I was tired and was just interested in cleaning/security. I made the mistake of selecting 'ok' at the screen where you choose your locales. I've seen a video and apparently 1 type gets saved as a default or something. I don't know how to reverse this so I was hoping I could get a little bit of advice.

Information I've saved just incase is my locale output, locale -a output, locale -a -v output. Etc/locale/default contains a text file saying #File generated by update-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8". /var/cache/localepurge/localelist contains quite a lot of locales, including en_US.UTF-8 (I'm not sure how it all works so sorry if this is just random information). In /var/lib/locales/supported.d I have and 'en' text file that contains about 15 different locales (I'm not sure why).

I've left the terminal open and it's at the screen after choosing locales to keep, giving an option for 'Use dpkg --path-exclude?' yes/no. I haven't tried interfering with it with interrupts or kill because I've read that doesn't have a great outcome. I've noticed at that time is when some locale.c and locale perl files were modified/accessed/created. As of now in terms of decreasing last modification time, (searched locale from /) it's localepurge/localelist, var/cache/localpurge, some locale.config file and there's also a locale.gen (x-application-genesis-rom) file.

I really am not sure what to do. I'd think I could avoid potential harm by possibly adding extra entries to some of the locale textfiles but I don't think that's a good idea. And I don't know what to do with the installation since I can't cancel it and I don't know what my selections truly imply when I only have the default en_US.UTF-8.

I do know that after the installation completes I could (possibly) do dpkg-reconfigure localepurge, there's a reinstall_debs.sh file that will appear, and 1 more file that seemed important after the installation.

If anyone has some advice it'd be appreciated, I know it's a little specific but I've honestly looked around for resources and couldn't find anything to assure me safety. Thank you

Comment: Please kill the process with `ctrl+c`, then look here and see if you will see this file `/usr/share/doc/localepurge/reinstall_debs.sh`

Comment: [word of caution](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/localepurge.8.html) here worth noting

Comment: I got an app _grive_ which won't work because my locale isn't what it uses so exercise caution

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+c didn't seem to affect it. I imagine since it's already in the process of installation, I'd have to use Ctrl+z or send a command to its id? I won't do that unless advised.

Comment: yes use that too it should stop it

Comment: I ran ps aux | grep 'Z' since there was 1 zombie process, and it lists the zombie process as [dpkg-preconfigu] <defunct> with the correct time it started. I don't know if that's significant. Does that mean the apt-get is just waiting for my response so it can carry on with deleting locales?

Should I answer the questions (I'm still on the 'Use dpkg --path-exclude?' one) and see what happens or attempt to interfere with it?

Answer (score 2):

If all you did was run `localepurge` then you have nothing to worry about. All it does is remove language support files for unneeded languages; those can easily be reinstalled from the System Settings / Language Support if you change your mind.

**Beware that `localepurge` *"will be automagically  invoked by  `dpkg`  upon  completion  of  any `apt` installation run"* (from [`man localepurge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/localepurge.8.html))**; I would suggest that you remove it with `sudo apt-get purge localepurge` after the first run. The manual page of `localepurge` has more information, including a warning that "it is a hack" and it "is  not  integrated  with Debian's  package  management system".

Comment: It's not an issue that I accidentally skipped the initial selection of locales to keep? Since none were picked, I thought the update-locale generates a default one (en_US.UTF-8) that is kept while it removes all other ones. My supported.d file has several locales listed and then there's the thing with the 10+ LC ...  = en_US.UTF-8 and 'LANGUAGE=en_US' also being listed in addition to LANG=en_US.UTF-8 for the locale command output.

Comment: I guess since all I have is the default one since I didn't choose any, aren't all applications going to be dysfunctional without other locales they used?

Comment: [word of caution](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/localepurge.8.html) here worth noting

Comment: @NotShrek see my link to buttress you statement.

Comment: @NotShrek: The applications will speak only American until you install support for other languages.

Comment: From `man localepurge`:  "This program does interfere with the Debian package management and does
       provoke strange, but usually harmless, behaviour  of  programs  related
       with  apt/dpkg  like dpkg-repack(1), debsums(1), reportbug(1), etc.  If
       you need to have any package in its full integrity  so  that  e.g.  the
       formerly  mentioned  programs  work  as  designed  by its author and as
       expected by  you,  deinstall  localepurge  temporarily  without
       purging  its configuration and reinstall the packages you need in their
       fully integral state".

Comment: Okay I guess I'm just worried it'll cause severe problems, especially since it chose the default mode. So after I either go through the prompts or send it a signal, is 'deinstall localepurge temporarily without purging its configuration' implying after reinstall broken packages, I need to reconfigure localpurge?

Comment: @NotShrek: Reinstall `localepurge` only if you want to run it again. On most systems the disk space reclaimed by `localpurge` is too little for the hassle.

Comment: Okay thanks. As for the process itself, do you recommend I just use ctrl+z on the terminal? There's a zombie process with bash as a parent and then terminal as the next one. Is sending SIGCHLD to the parent or some other signal a better idea?

Comment: Nevermind, I noticed in your original answer you said to purge it after the first run.